# PHP + Xdebug + VS Code: Bug on Debian 10?

Tags: php, debian, xdebug

When debugging in VS Code on Debian 10, local variables in a subroutine does not show in VC "Locals" when hitting a breakpoint.
Sample code:

```
function testbug($param1)
{
  $grappa="grappa 2";
  echo "Test: ".$grappa.$param1."</br>";
}
```

The `$grappa` variable does not show in a debug session "Locals" variables on Debian, but is present on Ubuntu.

Debian:

> Apache Version: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
>   Current PHP version: 7.3.14-1~deb10u1
>   Xdebug v2.7.0RC2

When running on a Ubuntu server, all is fine.

Ubuntu:

> Apache Version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
>   Current PHP version: 7.3.15-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
>   Xdebug v2.9.2

Can anyone advise? I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running an old Xdebug with Debian, a Release Candidate (2.7.0RC2) even. Upgrade Xdebug to the latest supported version (https://xdebug.org/docs/compat).

Install the `php-dev` and `php-pear` packages with apt, and then run: `pecl install xdebug`. (Full installation docs at https://xdebug.org/docs/install).

Comment: This is the newest available through official channels for Debian 10. apt-get update && apt-get upgrade: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. So, are you suggesting a move to unstable or a custom install of Xdebug?

Comment: Debian 10 ships a release candidate? That's a terrible thing of them to do. But yes, I would then suggest to install Xdebug from source (updated answer).

Comment: That helped :) Thank you @Derick!